# Characterizing linear functionals of norm less than $1$

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products, orthonormal

To my embarassement, I am struggling with the following elementary statement: if $V$ is a finite dimensional real vector space, endowed with an inner product and an orthonormal basis $\{ e_1, \dots, e_n \}$, then

$$\{ \phi \in V^* \mid | \phi (x) | \le \| x \| \} = \left\{ \phi \in V^* \mid \sum _{i=1} ^n \phi (e_i) ^2 \le 1 \right\} .$$

The $\supseteq$ inclusion is easy, using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:

$$ | \phi (x) | = \left| \sum _{i=1} ^n x_i \phi (e_i)\right| \le \| x \| \cdot \sqrt {\sum _{i=1} ^n \phi (e_i) ^2} \le \| x \| .$$

The $\subseteq$ inclusion, though, makes me feel miserable, since all the approaches that I attempt lead to the much coarser $\sum \limits _{i=1} ^n \phi (e_i) ^2 \le n $. What is then the smart inequality to use here, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is silly, but if you know $|\phi(x)| \leqslant \|x\|$ for all $x \in V$, can't you take $x = \sum_{i=1}^n \phi(e_i)e_i$, so $\phi(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \phi(e_i)^2$, and $\|x\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \phi(e_i)^2$, and $\phi(x)^2 = |\phi(x)|^2 \leqslant \|x\|^2$, therefore
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \phi(e_i)^2\right)^2 \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n \phi(e_i)^2,
$$
therefore $\sum_{i=1}^n \phi(e_i)^2 \leqslant 1$? I'll get me coat.

Comment: There is nothing silly here, I just hadn't thought about working with $x = \sum_{i=1}^n \phi(e_i)e_i$. Very nice proof, I appreciate especially its conciseness.

Comment: I think the reason it felt "silly" to me was that I had turned my back on any attempt at abstract understanding, and just thought of $\phi$ as a bunch of numbers acting on other bunches of numbers, when it is the most natural thing in the world to let $\phi$ act on itself, and see what happens. But I think I almost understand the same "natural" idea in a more abstract way now.

Answer (score 1):

We may write $\phi = \sum_{i=1}^n \phi_i e_i^*$, where $e_i^*$ is the dual basis defined by $e_i^*(a_1 e_1 + \cdots + a_n e_n) = a_i$. Observe that $$\phi_i = \phi(e_i).$$ (This can be seen by applying $\phi$ to $e_j$.)

Suppose that $| \phi(x) | \leq \| x\|$ for all $x \in V$. If you're farmiliar with functional analysis, you'll notice that another way to say this is that $\|\phi\| \leq 1$, where $\|\phi\| = \sup_{\|x\|=1} |\phi(x)|$ is the operator norm on $V^*$. Using our expansion $\phi = \sum_{i=1}^n \phi_i e_i^*$, we have
$$
\|\phi\| = \sup_{\|x\|=1} \left| \sum_{i=1}^n \phi_i e_i^*(x)\right| = \sup_{\|\vec x\|=1} \left| \vec{\phi} \cdot \vec x \right| = \left| \vec \phi \right|,
$$
where $\vec \phi = (\phi_1, \dots, \phi_n)$ and $\vec x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ are vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ formed by the coefficients of the vectors $\phi$ and $x$ in $V$ with respect to the basis $e_1, \dots, e_n$. The last step follows from taking $\vec x = \frac{\vec \phi}{\left| \vec \phi \right|}$ according to the case of equality in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Since $\|\phi\| \leq 1$ and the above shows $\|\phi\| = \left|\vec \phi\right|$, we must have $\left| \vec \phi \right| \leq 1$. Expanding this yields
$$
\left| \vec \phi \right| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \phi_i^2} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \phi(e_i)^2} \leq 1.
$$
Squaring gives the desired result.

Comment: This is nice, and starts to make sense of the calculation that had felt "silly" to me. Note that $V^*$ is itself an inner product space, as in e.g, P. R. Halmos, *Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces*, $\S67$, or G. C. Shephard, *Vector Spaces of Finite Dimension*, $\S5.4$; and $|\phi|$ is the norm of $\phi$ calculated with respect to this inner product; so what is really going on is that the two 'norms' of $\phi$, the 'functional analysis' norm $\|\phi\|$ and the 'linear algebra' norm  $|\phi|$, although defined in different ways, nevertheless have the same value. I find this oddly comforting. :)

Comment: One small correction: although you clearly define $\vec\phi$ as the real $n$-vector of coefficients of $\phi$ with respect to the dual orthonormal basis $(e_1^*, \ldots, e_n^*)$ of $V^*$, some words you use later ("the coefficients of the vectors $\phi$ and $x$") inadvertently seem to imply that $\phi$ is a vector in $V$, and that $\vec\phi$ is the real $n$-vector of coefficients of $\phi$ with respect to the orthonormal basis $(e_1, \ldots, e_n)$ of $V$. Perhaps what you had in mind is $\phi(x) = \langle x, y \rangle$ for all $x \in V$, where $y = \sum_{i=1}^n \phi_i e_i$ (my "silly" vector).

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear -- what I mean is the following. Since we're in finite dimensions, an $n$-dimensional $\mathbb R$-vector space $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ and to $V^*$: $$ v = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i \in V \leftrightarrow \vec v = (a_1, \dots, a_n) \in \mathbb R^n \leftrightarrow v^* = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i^* \in V^*. $$ In this notation, what the OP calls $\phi$ should be called $\phi^*$, and the corresponding vector in $V$ is $\phi$. That's the vector in $V$ I was referring to.

Comment: With this notation, then, for all $\phi, x \in V$, we have $\phi^*(x) = \langle x, \phi \rangle$; and for all $\phi, \psi \in V$, the inner product in $V^*$ is given (by definition, as in the two books I referred to) by $\langle \phi^*, \psi^* \rangle = \langle \psi, \phi \rangle$. (Note the inversion of order, which is needed for the complex case, although it doesn't make any difference in the real case.)

Comment: Yes, that's all correct, and I agree with what you said in your previous comment: the Riesz representation theorem says $\phi^* = \langle \cdot, \phi \rangle$.

Comment: In particular, then, $\|\phi^*\| = \sqrt{\langle \phi^*, \phi^* \rangle} = \sqrt{\langle \phi, \phi \rangle} = \|\phi\|$. Hence, $\|\phi^*\| \leqslant 1 \iff \|\phi\| \leqslant 1$, which summarises what was to be proved.